# SSH from external network into VMs running in openstack

Tags: ssh, external, openstack

I currently have two VM running on OpenStack. They are connected to three different networks with virtual links and they can ping each othe ron each of those networks. One of the networks is the public network (external network that is pre-made by openstack). This network is supposed to be external, however I can't ping the public network from my ubuntu that is running openstack. How do I access the public network on openstack from an external network, so that I can SSH into my VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information what is given in question here are few suggestions:

- If you are not pinging the external world check the routing table whether the correct 
  route is added with the public network interface.
- Then check the security group rules, whether the SSH is enabled or not.
- And then finally check the physical networks whether they are correctly connected to switch.

Comment: Solved it, SSH was not enabled and also needed to add routes